# Error when creating a biplot of stable isotope data using the package SIAR in R

Tags: r

I want to use the package 'SIAR' to create a biplot of d15N in function of d13C. 
My data has the same format as found in the guideline 
'http://sethnewsome.org/sethnewsome/EE_files/SIAR%20for%20Ecologists.pdf'.

The model however gives me an error.

> Model = siarmcmcdirichletv4(DataSIConsumer, DataSISource, corrections = 0, concdep = 0, iterations = 500000, burnin = 50000)
>   Error in the sources file - check this is numeric.
>   Problems with inputs: siar has not been run.

I don't understand how to solve this problem. The first column of the source data is not a character and might thus cause the error, but the guideline describes this format of dataset. 
How can I solve this error?